# `\left \{` fitting a box (not centered)

Tags: vertical-alignment

Is there some way to get a `\left\{` work correctly around an `array` environment if the latter is top aligned *(or whatever that is not vertically centered around the baseline)*

I can think of the two following ways :

1. use a manually adjusted `raisebox`
2. use a Ti*k*Z `matrix` environment with `left delimiter = \{`

Here is my example :

[image: the MWE]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}

What I would like : 
\raisebox{-.6em}%
{%
  $
  \left \{
    \begin{array}{l}
      1 + 1 = 2 \\ 
      2 + 2 = 4 \\ 
    \end{array}
  \right .
  $
}

What I get : 
$
\left \{
  \begin{array}[t]{l}
    1 + 1 = 2 \\ 
    2 + 2 = 4 \\ 
  \end{array}
\right .
$

%Also bad : $\left \{ \rule{5cm}{5cm} \right \}

\end{document}
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is exactly what the `delarray` package is for,

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{delarray}
\begin{document}


What I get : 
$
  \begin{array}[t]\{{l}.
    1 + 1 = 2 \\ 
    2 + 2 = 4 \\ 
  \end{array}
$

%Also bad : $\left \{ \rule{5cm}{5cm} \right \}

\end{document}
```

[image]